# How can I create a function instance of this TypeScript interface?

Tags: typescript, promise, mocking, jestjs, netsuite

The syntax of the interface has me confused. It looks overloaded but when I try to create a function with either signature the compiler tells me that the other signature is missing. The goal is to mock the function for a Jest unit test.

```
interface SearchResultSetEachFunction {
  promise(callback: (result: Result) => boolean): Promise<boolean>;
  (callback: (result: Result) => boolean): void;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not overloaded, it a function that also has a property named `promise`. You can use `Object.assign` to create such an object:

```
let fn: SearchResultSetEachFunction = Object.assign(function (callback: (result: Result) => boolean): void {

}, {
    promise(callback: (result: Result) => boolean): Promise<boolean> {
      return Promise.resolve(false)
    }
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsKBeKBvAvgWACgBLAO2AgCcAzAQwGNoBlCGiugCziVWeAFF67AGKISdYEQD2JbIShQwFSQFsi8CAAo6NZMgBG9ANYAuKBooIUwU1ysBKDAD4oeyZOQsSd0wAUlq9QAeV3dPRwBuOTNtXQM6EzMLbmtYS1QHdGcQjxovUwA3SSIAE0iCfAJCDzQqElNmVg5bHgh+QRExCWkMKAB5PQArCHEAOhp4eCIAcxINKlFxKRktHX0jU3M0lObgDKy3HLyoQpLZAnlCHAAaM-l5RRU1TRi1+I2kqxstvZcDz28oH5HkFsmFbnd5BZgIgKDIgQEICMku58ppaMh1HYovIKjg7EA)

Or in newer versions of typescript you can use a function declaration and directly assign the `promise` member in the same scope as the declaration to have ts recogize it as a new memeber:

```
function mockSearchResultSetEachFunction(callback: (result: Result) => boolean): void {

}
mockSearchResultSetEachFunction.promise = function (callback: (result: Result) => boolean): Promise<boolean> {
  return Promise.resolve(false)
}

let fn: SearchResultSetEachFunction = mockSearchResultSetEachFunction
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=70&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsKBeKBvAvgWACgBLAO2AgCcAzAQwGNoBlCGiugCziVWeAFF67AGKISdYEQD2JbIShQwFSQFsi8CAAo6NZMgBG9ANYAuKBooIUwU1ysBKDAD4oeyZOQsSd0wAUlq9QAeV3dPRwBuOTNtXQM6EzMLbmtYS1QHdGcQjxovUwA3SSIAE0iCfAJCKlFxKRllSXjmVg5bHgh+QRExCWktHX0jU3M0lLbgDKy3HLyoQpLZAnlCCoamljZOUd4BDm7a6QA6RRU1aExqnrrogbiEkeSbUcmXac9vKD9ToOywxfkLMBEBQZF8AhBDkl3PlNLRkOo7CtCIQPGgqCRTM1NuMdl0ar0ZJg1oYsa1th1dsJ8XUgA)